# multiprocessing over dictionary elements

Tags: python, python-multiprocessing, paramiko

**Objective:**

1. ssh to each device listed in an excel file, execute the command, capture the output and present the output in a tabular format (output table Column A: devicename, Column B: command output)
2. optimize the processing time with the use of multiprocessing to scale for 100s of devices

So far I am able to achieve this using the following code, however I feel there should be a better way of doing this.
[reference](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fKl2JW_qrso)

**Problem statement:**

1. my input is a dictionary instead of a list, as a workaround I converted it to list in the code below.
2. the target function need elements of dictionary as input
3. the output from each process (switchname and the command output) should be returned to main process to form the dataframe

**Sample Table from excel file**

| DeviceName | DeviceIPaddress |
| --- | --- |
| router1121 | 192.168.1.1 |
| router1122 | 192.168.1.2 |
| router1131 | 192.168.1.3 |
| router1132 | 192.168.1.4 |

**Sample Table converted to Dictionary**

```py
{0: {'DeviceName': 'router1121', 'DeviceIPaddress': '192.168.1.1'}, 1: {'DeviceName': 'router1122', 'DeviceIPaddress': '192.168.1.2'}, 2: {'DeviceName': 'router1131', 'DeviceIPaddress': '192.168.1.3'}, 3: {'DeviceName': 'router1132', 'DeviceIPaddress': '192.168.1.4'}}
```

Working code that needs optimization and simplification

```py
import multiprocessing
import paramiko
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import stdiomask

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

def connect_device(admin_username, admin_password, devicename, ipaddress):
    print(f"Trying to connect to {devicename}")
    
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(hostname=ipaddress, port=22, allow_agent=False, username=admin_username, password=admin_password)

    print(f"Connection established to {devicename}")

    command = "show interface description | i Gi1/0/23"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    out = stdout.read()
    ssh.close()
    return devicename, out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    df = exceltodataframe('Deviceinfo.xlsx', 'Devicedetails')

    # create dictionaries from the dataframes
    dfdict = df.T.to_dict()
    mylist = list(dfdict.items())

    admin_username = input("Enter the username: ")
    admin_password = stdiomask.getpass("Enter the password: ")

    def_dct_all = defaultdict(dict)
    
    with concurrent.futures.ProcessPoolExecutor() as executor:
        
        results = [executor.submit(connect_device, admin_username, admin_password, mylist[idx][1]['DeviceName'], mylist[idx][1]['DeviceIPaddress']) for idx, n in enumerate(mylist)]

        for index, f in enumerate(concurrent.futures.as_completed(results)):
            def_dct_all[index]['DeviceName'] = f.result()[0]
            def_dct_all[index]['Description'] = f.result()[1]

    df = pd.DataFrame(def_dct_all).T
    print(df)
```

Comment: What is your question? "Optimize my code for me" is off-topic here.

Comment: Sorry if I have not posted the question properly, i am looking for some advice on what methods would best achieve the objective, not the entire code itself

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to find another better way to achieve the objective by using Pool class of multiprocessing.

```py
import multiprocessing
import paramiko
from collections import defaultdict
import pandas as pd
import stdiomask

ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()

def connect_device(admin_username, admin_password, devicename, ipaddress):

    devicename = mylist[1]['DeviceName']
    ipaddress = mylist[1]['DeviceIPaddress']

    print(f"Trying to connect to {devicename}")
    
    ssh.set_missing_host_key_policy(paramiko.AutoAddPolicy())

    ssh.connect(hostname=ipaddress, port=22, allow_agent=False, username=admin_username, password=admin_password)

    print(f"Connection established to {devicename}")

    command = "show interface description | i Gi1/0/23"
    stdin, stdout, stderr = ssh.exec_command(command)
    out = stdout.read()
    ssh.close()
    return devicename, out

if __name__ == '__main__':
    
    df = exceltodataframe('Deviceinfo.xlsx', 'Devicedetails')

    # create dictionaries from the dataframes
    dfdict = df.T.to_dict()
    mylist = list(dfdict.items())

    admin_username = input("Enter the username: ")
    admin_password = stdiomask.getpass("Enter the password: ")

    p = multiprocessing.Pool()
    result = p.map(connect_device, mylist)

    def_dct_all = defaultdict(dict)
    
    for r in range(len(result)):
        def_dct_all[r]['DeviceName'] = result[r][0]
        def_dct_all[r]['Description'] = result[r][1].decode("utf-8").rstrip()

    resultdf = pd.DataFrame(def_dct_all).T
    print(resultdf)
```